# spring batch reader operation in microservice projects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I use spring batch. My projects are written with microservice architecture. I'm shooting data in Reader with the feign client.
when I pull all the data with the feign client, the java heap swells. what kind of method should I apply for this situation. if I do paging, how will I maintain the consistency of the data? what kind of solution should be created for this situation.

Spring batch core version: 4.3.7

```
    @StepScope
    @Bean(name = "paymentReader")
    public ListItemReader<PaymentDto> reader() {
        ServiceResponse<List<PaymentDto>> result = paymentClient.getPaymentList();
        return new ListItemReader<>(result.getData());
    }

    private Step createStepFirst(ItemWriter<PaymentDto> createWriter, ItemProcessor<PaymentDto, PaymentDto> itemProcessor, ListItemReader<PaymentDto> reader) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(StepName.STEPFIRST)
                .<PaymentDto, PaymentDto>chunk(100)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(itemProcessor)
                .writer(createWriter).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I proceeded by extending the AbstractPagingItemReader class.

```
public class FeignClientPagingReader extends AbstractPagingItemReader<PaymentDto> {

    private final FeignClientService feignClientService;

    public FeignClientPagingReader(FeignClientService feignClientService, int pageSize) {
        this.feignClientService = feignClientService;
        this.setPageSize(pageSize);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doReadPage() {
        List<PaymentDto> paymentDtoList = feignClientService.findPaymentList(
                this.getPage(), this.getPageSize()
        );
        this.results = paymentDtoList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doJumpToPage(int itemIndex) {
    }
}
```